# Upgrading CXF to 2.7.5 is throwing JAXBException

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I recently upgraded the CXF libraries from 2.2.11 to 2.7.5. And this is throwing IllegalAnnotationsException error. I have listed below the error along with more details about the application.

I used wsdl2java along with xjc for generating the binding classes from the xsd files. So after this, we have multiple object factory classes in different packages. Some of the object factory classes have same method name, but they are in different packages though. So it compiles fine as per the spec from JAXB.

But during the run time, i get this below error.

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 34 counts        of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    The element name {urn:com.company.myproject.v4}DateEntered has more than one mapping.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.company.myproject.specificmodule.v2.ObjectFactory.createDateEntered(javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar)
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.company.myproject.commontypes.v2.ObjectFactory.createDateEntered(javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar)
```

This worked absolutely fine with CXF 2.2.11. Not sure why this is failing in the latest CXF. I tried generating the wsdl2java with CXF 2.7.5, but no luck. Tried several options by customising the JAXB bindings to have a different methodname, but that also did not work.

Can you please suggest me what is going wrong here? I strongly feel that there is some CXF setting which could do the trick as the same object factory classes worked fine with older version of CXF.